# How to get 'command-line intellisense' (TAB TAB) to work with a Python script?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, intellisense

My Python script accepts a number of options such as the following:

```
python ./Controller.py create 1
python ./Controller.py destroy
```

Is there anyways I can get intellisense to work in the command-line? For instance, typing the following:

```
python ./Controller.py <TAB><TAB>
```

should give the following:

```
create - <description>
destroy - <description>
```

Is there a good way to do this in a portable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bash, this feature is known as Bash Completion. Other shells may have similar functionality. Here's the official reference for it: [Programmable Completion](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html).

It's important to keep in mind this is a feature of the *shell*, not of Python or the script you're invoking.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the only way to do something along these lines is to provide help when the user enters something like `python ./Controller.py -h`. Take a look at the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module for hints on how to incorporate it into your script.